# Will I lose the data on the second partition when I install Windows 7 on the first partition?

Tags: windows, installation, partitioning

I am currently using Windows XP SP3 and want to install Windows 7 on my computer. It has 2 partitions, and I kept all the important data on the partition which doesn't contain OS, so does installing the new Windows works the same like reinstalling the same Windows on the computer? What I mean is, does it only format the partition that contains OS, the one I choose to install the new OS?

Comment: oh thank you, i thought that was something different, didn't bother to  read it...:)

Answer (score 3):

yes you can keep your data on any partition or seperate hdd while you install to another locaion. just make sure you dont select to delete or format any parition you want to keep while using any windows installer and all will be ok.    in windows installer they will label disk as (I am pretty sure correct me if wrong) Sd0 and sd1  you can familiarize yourself with your systems disk by looking at your disk management.

right click on my computer. choose manage.  choose disk management from left menu and examine your disks.

if you need more assistance just let me know